# JIRA / Bitbucket report of JIRA stories completed between 2 Git tags

Tags: report, bitbucket, jira

I have JIRA and Bitbucket integrated (e.g. you can create a branch from a JIRA story and you can click back to go to the JIRA story from Bitbucket).

I want to be able to generate a report in JIRA or Bitbucket that will give a list of JIRA stories that were completed between 2 Git tags.  For example, given a start Git tag of 1.0.0 and an end Git tag of 1.0.5, there have been many commits done to complete 3 JIRA stories: 1111, 1112 and 1113.  I want the report to return with a list of the 3 JIRA stories:

- http://dev.jira.com/1111
- http://dev.jira.com/1112
- http://dev.jira.com/1113

Anyone aware of a plugin that can do this?  Or, how would you approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Git Changelog](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/se.bjurr.changelog.git-changelog-for-bitbucket/server/overview) plugin:

> Creates a changelog, or releasenotes, for any GIT repo in Bitbucket
>   Server